# How to attach a certificate with WCF service with tcp binding by code

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, tcp

i got a sample code which show how to attach a certificate with WCF service with tcp binding by coding.

```
NetTcpBinding b = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
b.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
Uri netTcpAdddress = new Uri("net.tcp://baseAddress");
ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator), netTcpAdddress);
sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Contoso.com");
sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), b, "TcpCalculator");
sh.Open();
```

i am trying what is the meaning of this line

```
sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Contoso.com");
```

where wcf service will run there could be many certificate may exist in that pc. how to mention which certificate i need to attach with my service?

what is the meaning of StoreLocation.LocalMachine ? does it mean localhost ?

what is the meaning of StoreName.My ?

what is My ? is it any folder name if yes then what is the full path of this folder.

what is X509FindType.FindByIssuerName ?

what does it means because a single user may create or have many certificate. so how do i point to a specific certificate ?

i can create many certificate where i could use the word "Contoso.com"

my question is how to programmatically specify or identify a specific certificate because a user may create many certificate so how do i differentiate two certificate by code.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation on the [`SetCertificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in question. It appears that my previous tip on [SSL over TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806286/few-query-about-wcf-with-ssl-certificate/22817737#22817737) helped out.

> what is the meaning of StoreLocation.LocalMachine ? does it mean
>   localhost ?

No, it doesn't mean localhost. It refers to the X.509 certificate store assigned to the local machine (**Computer Account** in [MMC snap-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

> what is the meaning of StoreName.My ?

It refers to the X.509 certificate store for personal certificates.

> what is My ? is it any folder name if yes then what is the full path
>   of this folder.

**My** in this particular instance is referring to the store of personal certificates for the Local Machine. Here is a view of the structure in MMC.

[image]

> what is X509FindType.FindByIssuerName ?

It means that the certificate you are setting on the Host will be the first certificate that matches the `IssuerName` of the value you have provided which is `"Contoso.com"`. `SetCertificate` will try to find a certificate in the **Local Machine**'s store of **Personal** certificates that matches this criteria.

> what does it means because a single user may create or have many
>   certificate. so how do i point to a specific certificate ?

As you have suggested, the `IssuerName` may not be a unique identifier if the machine that the Host is running on has multiple certificates from the same Issuer. It is much better to use another [X509FindType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum member such as `FindBySerialNumber` or better yet `FindByThumbprint`.

So this is how I would uniquely identify a certificate to set on the Host that was in the Local Machine's store of Personal certificates.

```
sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, 
        /* Thumbprint - SHA1 hash value for the Cert */);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer in detail. verey vertificate has expire date so if any certificate expire without my knowledge then what could happen? wcf service will may not work or any error will occur.

Comment: when we purchase any certificate and when any certificate expire the do we need to purchase the certificate from the company again or we can just renew it with minimum cost?

Comment: those people who purchase certificate for using with web site or wcf service then how get intimation before certificate gets expire....is there any process exist. thanks

Comment: when we use SetCertificate() function then can we specify something different than StoreName.My ? how to see & get thumb print of a certificate ? please guide because i am new in certificate & wcf.